# <body> section jumps when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've designed my website to have a small quick navigation bar underneath the website header and I coded it so that when you scroll down it becomes fixed once it hits the top and unfixed into its original position when you scroll back up. But I've noticed now that the bar, when the site loads, seems to act as if it was in absolute but when I immediately start scrolling the static position segments underneath it (The post section) jumps down as if it finally made the bar relative. Can anyone help?

CODE: http://codepen.io/PorototypeX/pen/qgDtb

(sorry for the reposts and large code post. still new to the site)

Comment: [Minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please

Comment: Please narrow the code to describe the problem... you posted everything here.

Comment: Sorry dude, my bad. I posted the whole thing since I didn't know what could be causing this issue.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/

Comment: The navigation goes from `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` when you start scrolling. ( When the navigation is set to `absolute`, the content will ignore its vertical height. When you start scrolling and `position` changes to `relative`, the content acknowledges its height and is pushed down.  ) --- Why you've set navigation to `absolute` by default, is something I don't quite understand.

Comment: Well when I was originally trying to figure out how to do the sticky nav bar feature I thought that absolute positioning would be ideal since it doesn't take up a specific content area. after I figured it out I guess I forgot that tiny thing I forgot to delete. But thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this from your CSS:

```
#navcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 46.62px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I over looked that since it didn't play a major role before and accidentally left it there. Thanks for catching that for me.